# How to update multiple rows and also prevent sql injection?

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST["submit"] ) ) {

    foreach( $_POST["id"] AS $id ) {
        $may_tc_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["may_tc_s1"][$id] );
        $may_ac_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["may_ac_s1"][$id] );
        $jun_tc_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["jun_tc_s1"][$id] );
        $jun_ac_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["jun_ac_s1"][$id] );
        $jul_tc_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["jul_tc_s1"][$id] );
        $jul_ac_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["jul_ac_s1"][$id] );
        $aug_tc_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["aug_tc_s1"][$id] );
        $aug_ac_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["aug_ac_s1"][$id] );
        $sep_tc_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["sep_tc_s1"][$id] );
        $sep_ac_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["sep_ac_s1"][$id] );
        $oct_tc_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["oct_tc_s1"][$id] );
        $oct_ac_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["oct_ac_s1"][$id] );
        $nov_tc_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["nov_tc_s1"][$id] );
        $nov_ac_s1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["nov_ac_s1"][$id] );
        $s1_t1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["s1_t1"][$id] );
        $s1_t2 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["s1_t2"][$id] );
        $s1_t3 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["s1_t3"][$id] );

        $update = " UPDATE `attendence` SET 
        `may_tc_s1` = '$may_tc_s1',
        `may_ac_s1` = '$may_ac_s1',
        `jun_tc_s1` = '$jun_tc_s1',
        `jun_ac_s1` = '$jun_ac_s1',
        `jul_tc_s1` = '$jul_tc_s1',
        `jul_ac_s1` = '$jul_ac_s1',
        `aug_tc_s1` = '$aug_tc_s1',
        `aug_ac_s1` = '$aug_ac_s1',
        `sep_tc_s1` = '$sep_tc_s1',
        `sep_ac_s1` = '$sep_ac_s1',
        `oct_tc_s1` = '$oct_tc_s1',
        `oct_ac_s1` = '$oct_ac_s1',
        `nov_tc_s1` = '$nov_tc_s1',
        `nov_ac_s1` = '$nov_ac_s1',
        `s1_t1` = '$s1_t1',
        `s1_t2` = '$s1_t2',
        `s1_t3` = '$s1_t3'
         WHERE `idatten` =$id LIMIT 1 ; ";
        mysql_query( $update ) or die( mysql_error() );
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM attendence WHERE branch = 'cs' AND attendence.semester=1 ORDER BY attendence.rollno";
$res = mysql_query( $sql ) or die( mysql_error() );
if ( mysql_num_rows( $res ) > 0 ) {

    echo '<form method="post">';
    echo' <table border="1" align="center">';
    echo' <tr>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">ID</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">Student Name</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">Roll No</div></th>';
    echo' <th colspan="2"><div align="center">May</div></th>';
    echo' <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Jun</div></th>';
    echo' <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Jul</div></th>';
    echo' <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Aug</div></th>';
    echo' <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Sep</div></th>';
    echo' <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Oct</div></th>';
    echo' <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Nov</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">T1</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">T2</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">T3</div></th>';
    echo' </tr>';
    echo' <tr>';
    echo' <th><div align="center"></div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center"></div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center"></div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">TC</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">AC</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">TC</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">AC</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">TC</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">AC</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">TC</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">AC</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">TC</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">AC</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">TC</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">AC</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">TC</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center">AC</div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center"></div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center"></div></th>';
    echo' <th><div align="center"></div></th>';
    echo' </tr>';
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {
    echo' <tr>';
    echo' <td>'.$row["idatten"] . '</td>';
    echo' <td>'.$row["username"] . '</td>';
    echo' <td>'.$row["rollno"] .'</td>';
    echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="may_tc_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["may_tc_s1"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="may_ac_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["may_ac_s1"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="jun_tc_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["jun_tc_s1"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="jun_ac_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["jun_ac_s1"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="jul_tc_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["jul_tc_s1"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="jul_ac_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["jul_ac_s1"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="aug_tc_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["aug_tc_s1"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="aug_ac_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["aug_ac_s1"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="sep_tc_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["sep_tc_s1"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="sep_ac_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["sep_ac_s1"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="oct_tc_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["oct_tc_s1"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="oct_ac_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["oct_ac_s1"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="nov_tc_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["nov_tc_s1"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="2" type="text" name="nov_ac_s1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["nov_ac_s1"] . '"></td>';    
    echo' <td><input size="4" type="text" name="s1_t1[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["s1_t1"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="4" type="text" name="s1_t2[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["s1_t2"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <td><input size="4" type="text" name="s1_t3[' . $row["idatten"] . ']" value="' . $row["s1_t3"] . '"></td>';
    echo' <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="' . $row["idatten"] . '">';
    echo' </tr>';
    echo' <tr>';
    }}
    echo'  <td colspan="20"><div align="center">  <input type="submit" onblur="t1()" name="submit" value="Update Record"></div></td>';  
    echo' </tr>';
    echo' </table>';
    echo '</form>';
?>
<!-- End of cs1_s1 ---></div>
```

this is my code to upload multiple records. and its working fine but have to place all the table inside the if only which is tedious to do . as i have multiple  pages to do and is this type of coding safe like is it prone to sql injection or any thing else if it is how to make it safe. and i need to have seven more tables on the same page but if i place all the seven tables it pops an error database not found. so how do i call 7 to 8 of them on the same page.

Comment: Your update query is fine. Secondly why you are making whole table with php? Make an table in html and just embed php within it. In this way your echos in php will no need. in your html **<td> <?php echo $row["idatten"] ?></td>**

Comment: But can you just show me how to do it plz as i am new to this

Comment: It seems safe, but very error prone and low maintainability. Are the table columns fixed? Can you briefly describe what is this system about so we can help in how to make it a little bit more efficient. What is TC/AC? S1/S2 are semesters?

Comment: tc is total class and ac is attended class and s1 is subject1 and s2 is subject2

Comment: i am working with  Dreamweaver and it generates update code for one record only but i need for multiple row for which i worked on this code and no idea of safety measures and to work efficiently plz help me in this

Answer (score 0):

Create a test.php page paste this code in it.

```
<form method="post">
<table border="1" align="center">';
<tr>
<th><div align="center">ID</div></th>
<th><div align="center">Student Name</div></th>
<th><div align="center">Roll No</div></th>
</tr>

<?php 
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["idatten"]; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row["username"]; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row["rollno"]; ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>
</form>
```